# Как передать указатель на функцию в DLL?

Tags: python, dll

Есть DLL библиотека которую надо подключить к моему скрипту. Подключаю через ctypes

```
imoport ctypes
dll = ctypes.WinDLL('myDLL.dll')
```

в этой библиотеке есть функция SetCallback

```
bool SetCallback(tcallback pCallback);
// Тип tcallback объявлен следующим образом:
typedef bool (*tcallback)(BYTE* pData);
```

есть у меня функция

```
def myfync():
    print "Hello from dll"
```

Как мне передать её в функцию `SetCallback()`?

Comment: Ещё актуально! Очень!

Comment: Ну во-первых, у аргумента SetCallback есть аргумент -- указатель на BYTE. А во-вторых, а что не получается? Определить через WINFUNCTYPE (см. 15.17.1.17) тип callback'а, затем, уже этим типом сам callback, и уже его задать параметром SetCallback. Вроде так...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ох, откуда же вы берете такие задачи =)

```
/* main.c -> main.so (или .dll в windows) */

typedef void (*callback)();

void mainfunction(void *F) {
        ((callback)F)(); /* вызывает функцию */
}
```

Идем в питон (Python):

```
>>> from ctypes import CFUNCTYPE
>>> def pyfn():
...     print "Called the Python function"
... 
>>> CWRAPPER = CFUNCTYPE(None)

>>> wrapped_py_func = CWRAPPER(pyfn)
>>> main.mainfunction(wrapped_py_func)
Called the Python function
```